# Is there any way to do automation/repetition based on user input?

Tags: automation

Like iMacros in Windows, is there any way which can automate my task?

I had tried so many application like MacroDroid but hadn't got my aim to be complete. As I want similar work like iMacros, I want to open one link and then click some elements and then save the webpage to external storage and I want this task to repeat. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Repetitouch: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cygery.repetitouch.free

It Allows you to input a set of touches and swipes, and the app will repeat exactly what you have recorded.  You can also set stuff like delays, speed, or amount of repetitions.

Comment: Sorry, but since the app is not available on the Play Store anymore, future readers won't be able to download and use it (you may still be able to see the entry on the Play Store if you have installed it before).